# PHP template with HTML template

Tags: php, html

I am in middle of using HTML template and I want to convert it to PHP so it will be easier to manage since multiple files are going to be created.

Is it better to use php class and generate the templates in the pages?

For example:

```
$Template = new Template();

$Template->page_header();
$Template->tag("open-div");
$Template->search_bar();
$Template->tag("close-div");
```

or use HTML to generate the same?

I know this question has been bit to death but different people ask questions of different nature. So pardon me if this is a report I just needed a short answer or suggestions about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, can get messy, I'd just use something like http://code.google.com/p/html-object/

Comment: How would this help? Why don't you simply use HTML. Just make sure you have an external CSS file. When you need to change the look, update the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It does have CSS, I wasn't talking about the CSS though. Different pages have different structure like 1,2,3 horizontal and vertical columns. So creating the template in PHP would be make it easier to access the elements and div classes/ids to use in different pages.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, why don't you use a PHP framework which has all of this functionality already built into it? You can operate your system with OOP and provide your HTML views with PHP variables. Popular frameworks include:

- [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

Or, if you really want to retain control over your own code, look into using a template engine like:

- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)
- [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)

Comment: I have used CodeIgniter before, it is pretty good to use. I'll take a look into that again.

Comment: It'll save you hours of coding something that somebody else has already written (to a higher quality most likely). CodeIgniter is a good beginners framework - ZF2 can be slightly intimidating at times.

Comment: I am not that of a beginner. :) Anyways, sometimes it's fun and adventures to make frameworks of your own to learn and explore more possibilities, not that CI is not a great tool.

Comment: I completely agree. Depends whether you're using the framework to get jobs done quickly (i.e. in your profession) or whether you're just doing it to learn more. If it's the latter, build your own :)

Comment: I am building my own to get the jobs done quickly. You know what I mean. It's not that big of a framework it's just something in small scale to get something done with ease.